# how click on word in iframe and display popupbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
 <iframe id ="iframe" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width:100%; border: none"></iframe>
<script>
 $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://20minutes.fr') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
                            document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.write(data.contents + '');

                        });
                    </script>
<script>
                var p = $('#paragraph'); //create variable to store text

                p.html(function (index, oldHtml) {
                    return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>')
                });

                p.click(function (event) {
                //gets translation

                            document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = '<i>' + originalwordTextDiv + '</i>' + '<br>' + translationTextDiv;


                        })
                    }

                });
                $(function () {
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false
                    });

                    $("body").click(function () {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    });
                });



            </script>
```

In the script above when I click on a word in the page displayed in the iframe, no popupbox is shown. I have got around the javascript same origin policy, the objective of the code is to display a translation of a word that has been clicked on, on a foreign news website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.